# New line after the command prompt

Tags: terminal, prompt

Is there any way I can configure terminal applications to display command text from front of `$` to under the user name on terminal window? See image attached. I use `terminator`.

[image]

Comment: Note, though, that vertical screen space is more limited than horizontal.  Modern displays typically have aspect ratios of 16:9 (e.g. 1920x1080) or 16:10 (e.g. 1920x1200).  It's easy to have a terminal window far wider than you need it to be (which is great for viewing log files), but adding extra line-feeds to the prompt further reduces the limited number of lines that can display meaningful information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

POSIXly:

```
$ NL='
'
$ PS1=${PS1}${NL}
$
<cursor here>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but it only stays there for the current session. On restarting the terminal (in my case, the Terminator), the cursor goes back to the same old position, the front of command prompt. Can I do this permanently?

Comment: Add it to your rc file, `.bashrc`, `.zshrc` ...

Answer (score 6):

In `bash` (and `yash`), add a newline `\n` at the end of the `PS1` environment variable.

For example:

```
$ echo "$PS1"
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]\u@\h:\w\$ 

$ PS1='\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]\u@\h:\w\$\n'

$
echo "$PS1"
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]\u@\h:\w\$\n
```

To make it permanent, save it in your shell startup configuration file (for example `~/.bashrc`):

```
echo "PS1='\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]\u@\h:\w\$\n'" >>~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way in `bash`, `yash` is:

```
$ PS1="$PS1\n"
```